# Self Reference Eloquent Laravel for quote Posting

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
+------------+
|  replies   |
+------------+
|    id      |
| parent_id  |
| contents   |
| created_by |
| updated_by |
+------------+
```

And below is in Model

```
public function referrer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Reply', 'parent_id','id');
}

public function referral()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Reply','id','parent_id');
}
```

but when I want to show comment with id based on parent_id

```
{{ $reply->referrer->contents }}
```

but gives me error

```
Trying to get property 'contents' of non-object
```

thank you

Comment: There might be no referrer for that reply and you want to print its contents that's why it is giving this error. Check if you are getting any referrer or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your relations code:

```
public function referrer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Reply', 'parent_id');
}

public function referral()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Reply', 'parent_id');
}
```

BelongsTo: retrieve parent (referrer in this case) for child

hasOne: retrieve child (referral in this case) for parent

Comment: sorry, actually it is contents in the table

Comment: As was mentioned above, there might be no referrer. You can check it by: {{ $reply->referrer ? $reply->referrer->contents : '' }}